# Unable to disable Secure Boot in ASUS EUFI bios

Tags: bios, secure-boot

I've just bought a new windows 10 machine from Scan, and I need to disable secure boot to get various Ubuntu things working.  However, the secure boot is enabled in the bios and greyed out so I can't change it.

[image]

I have tried adding both an admin and user password (and restarting), but that didn't help.

Comment: Have you enabled Advanced Mode (F7 key or other) and did "Clear Secure Boot keys"?

Comment: I'll try that, thx